# Posting File and List to MVC controller Using FormData MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I am trying to post a file and a list to an MVC controller using FormData but the list seems to be empty on hitting the controller.

Form Data:

```
 var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("AttachedFile", files[0]);
                formData.append("Items", invoice.serialize());
                formData.append("CustomerId", 1);
                formData.append("RevenueHeadId", demandNoteObject.RevenueHeadId);
```

Model:

```
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int RevenueHeadId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase AttachedFile { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(InvoiceCreateModel model)
```

JQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "")",
                    datatype: "Json",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
```

Comment: Where you call action of controller

Comment: @evilGenius I have included that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "yourControllerName")',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) { ...}
        });
```

try this

Edit 
Because Items is a collection of objects, you have to add each one of them with an index

```
var index = 0;
for(var item of invoice){
    var pair = item[key];
    formData.append("Items[" + index + "].yourField", pair.yourField);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Controller name is not the issue. I excluded the name on purpose. All the data passed hits the on controller except the list.

Comment: Listen, your view is based on a model and you have generated the controls inside <form> tags?

Comment: The RevenueHeadId, CustomerId, AttachedFile have values at the controller level except Items.

Comment: Their data gets to the controller, but the Items are empty